# Changing Title of home page in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I am totally new to Joomla. I am trying to help a friend whose ISP has stopped support (for some internal reasons). We need to change the title of the home page.

1) The first place i made a change was in the 'Front Page Manager'. I changed the 'Title' column. The 'Show Title' parameter on this page is set to 'Global'. Yet the new title does not appear.

2) I then downloaded the entire site , consisting of 10,000 files and searched for the old title in all the files. I found the old title in one file which seemed to be used for SEO pruposes , since it had a whole lot of companies and their titles. I uploaded this file. No effect.

3) I then browsed through the database (MySQL) and changed old titles found in MetaKey and MetaDescription columns to new title. I think i checked all tables (almost 100 odd tables). No effect.

4) I found the old title in the 'Top Menu' item and changed it too.

I know this is a bit ambiguous but how could i troubleshoot the source of this title which does not get changed ?

Thanks,
Chak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titles in Joomla come from several places. As Legycsapo said, the first place you should look is the default menu item. In the Parameters (System) the Page Title should override any other setting unless you have an extension that sets the page title. The Show Page Title option determines if the title shows up in the content, it does not affect the page title.

Comment: Ok thanks. How can i find if some extension has been added which is setting the page title ? Is there any easy way to find out ...

Comment: You would have to be familiar with the extension unfortunately. Some of the SEF components allow you to set custom titles for example. Also, SEOSimple and BNRSEO both auto generate a title so you will have to look at both plugins and components to see if there is something else affecting your titles.

Comment: Thanks. I guess some such thing is populating it externally.

Comment: One easy way to figure out which extension is rewriting your titles is to disable them. If you go in to the admin in the Extensions > Install/Uninstall menu, you can click the links to get to the installed Components and Plugins managers. Simply disable them one at a time then refresh the page. Once the title changes, you will know which extension is the culprit.

Comment: Okay Brent, before i could try that , my friend transferred the problem back to the developers. so i couldnt figure out. But what if the Developers have set the Title in some compiled software which they have in the bin which overrides all plugins and components and changes Title ? Is that a possibility ?

Comment: Due to the order of operation of the Joomla framework, you could always override a title with a plugin that is triggered after all of the events in a component or module. I don't use any of them, but there are SEO extensions that allow you to set titles, presumably those would be triggered late in the process in order to insure the correct title is displayed.

Comment: In my case I am getting 'HOME' appended or prefixed to the overide title I specified in the setttings. I am talking in my case about the title tag. Is anyone knowing why I cannot remove the home from the tag content.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change it in the menu options. In the mainmenu, click on the "Home" link, or whatever you write for Frontpage, and there are options in the right. The last one is the parameters, system, there is a "Website title" input box. Try there !

Comment: The Home menu, in Main menu has Parameters system. It has a Page title whose value is 'Welcome to the Frontpage'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the home page title in the Control Panel Configuration.

In the Site tab you have the Site Name which is what will be written in the page title.

Comment: I changed the 'site name' but that does not appear in the title of home page.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is, if you have SEF urls enabled, joomla has a native plugin called SEOsimple. Look under Plugin Manager, click on it and change the title to either disable so that it takes the title by default from global configuration or your custom one.